# How do I insert numbers into a table in MS ACCESS without using any type of JOIN?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table with 30 columns which I have sorted descending using the query. Now I would like to add a column with a list of numbers to this table such that 1 represents the highest of the sorted column and so on.

I have sorted the columns based on which I need to number and for the numbering I have tried using a `COUNT()` function, but it keeps returning zeros for all records.

```
SELECT Count([Field1]) AS Expr1
FROM MasterT2
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You will find that people here are more likely to help if you show that you have made some effort on your own.

Comment: Thank you Jonny. I have added the details.

Comment: Why can't you use a join? I don't know that you would need to, but it's just an interesting stipulation.

Comment: Are you open to a VBA solution?

Comment: @Gene: Sure. VBA is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you append a selection of records where there is an ORDER
BY clause, into a table with an autonumber field, an incremental one, not a
random one, the insertion will follow the ORDER BY sequence and thus, the
autonumber will supply the rank. So, if the table has an autonumber field,
just append the *sorted* records to the table (without supplying a value
for the autonumber field, in the insert statement).

Source: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/can-you-autonumber-in-a-query-based-on-sorting-order.1170632/

Answer (score 0):

One of numerous possible methods.

in your post, it says you want to add a column to the table, so.. step 1. in Design View add a column, call it whatever you want, give it a number type and save.  In VBA:

```
dim db as DAO.database
dim rs as DAO.recordset
dim count as int

count = 0
set db = currentdb
set rs = db.openrecordset("SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE ORDER BY YOURFIELD",dbopenDynaset)
if rs.countrecords > 0 THEN
  rs.movefirst
  DO WHILE not rs.eof
    rs.update
    rs!OrderField = count
    rs.update
    count = count + 1
  loop
end if

set rs = nothing
set db = nothing
```